# How to make a program/process a service under SysV-style init?

Tags: debian, services, daemon, sysvinit

I wonder how can I make a regular application like for instance `noip2` updater a system process. I use Debian 6.0.2. For now I have it like this :

- the binary is in the `/usr/local/bin/` as `noip2` file
- the 'script' that launches is added to `/etc/rc.local`

How can I make it a system service to be able to run/stop it with e.g. `service` command ?

Comment: You should probably tell us (Unix and Linux users) what makes something a "service", and what the "service" command does.  I have only a vague idea how that relates to the Unix/Linux idea of a "daemon process".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I found, [`noip2` includes the script `/etc/init.d/noip2`](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/i386/noip2/filelist), (also [here, for those not running Debian right now](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/No_IP_Manual.html#10454)) which should already be all you need.  I'm not sure how `services` interacts with the scripts in `/etc/init.d`, but in general you could run

```
/etc/init.d/noip2 start
```

to start the `noip2` service and

```
/etc/init.d/noip2 stop
```

to stop it.  Have a look at the script, it shows how to wrap any such process into a system service (with a pidfile, for example)  using [`start-stop-daemon`](http://man.cx/start-stop-daemon%288%29/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I see `noip` is not available for `squeeze` [link](http://packages.debian.org/stable/allpackages)

Comment: Indeed, [it has been removed](http://packages.qa.debian.org/n/no-ip/news/20120109T132956Z.html) and there is no maintainer. (See also [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=630027).)  Probably time to **(a)** take over maintaining the package or **(b)** look for an alternative.